# Making a class file in IntelliJ

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea

I have a question and was wondering if you could please answer it for me. I am trying to make a class file (circle C) bit instead it created a java file (square J). I have watched online youtune video of intelliJ but it didnt help. I used JDK version 14.0.1. I only used JDK version of 11.0.1 but still had the same problem.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand whats is .class and what it .java . Simply when you create new java class and compile it you get a .class file that is understandable by jvm. Please read the basics of java before proceeding further

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. When I right click on my source file. Then once i create a class name it should appear as a class file. However, that doesn't happen and instead it creates a java file. I watched intelliJ tutorial videos and it creates a class file but mine does not.   Please see this video as reference.  At 3 minute mark is when I encounter a problem.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_XxH66lm3U&t=192s

Comment: Hope you understand once you compile your .java file compiler will generate .class file that understand by jvm.  In intelij what it ment by class is conceptually java class. Not the .class file. If you have seen any tutorials that creates .class files right sway please mention the link

Comment: Please go through the video tutorial you tagged carefully. It’s mentioned there that it will create the .java file. So watch carefully and try to understand.

Comment: Yes I understand that but I need step by step process. If you could help with that I would greatly appreciate it. When i create my java file i dont know how to compile it so it gives me a class file. I clicked on Build button in intelliJ but it still hasnt given me a class file. I have already went thru the tutorial several times and had had same problems